# Dynamic Programming recursive or iterative

Tags: dynamic-programming

Can Dynamic Programming be applied in an "iterative" and a "recursive" way or is it good practice to apply it only one of the ways?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, DP can be applied to both.

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Then you have [Dynamic Programming: From novice to advanced](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static) and [A Tutorial on Dynamic Programming](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/dynamic/dynamic.html)

For the first tutorial, you will find links to TopCoder.com problems for practice (each of these problems have also an [Editorial](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/Algorithm+Problem+Set+Analysis) explaining the idea behind the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Dynamic programming can be seen (in many cases) as a recursive solution implemented in reverse.

Normally, in a recursion, you would calculate `x(n+1) = f(x(n))` with some stop condition for `n=0` (or some other value).

In many cases the function `f` is some min/max function, but it doesn't have to be.
Also, the function doesn't have to take a single variable.

Dynamic programming would solve this problem by calculating `f(0)`, then `f(1)`, then `f(2)` etc.

With more than one variable, there would normally be some natural order to calculate the function.

An example that dynamic programming can solve:
You are given 3 golf clubs. Each golf club can send a golf ball x units of distance forward (for example, 24, 37 and 54 units). The question is: can you hit a hole that is exactly 200 units away? And if you can, what's the minimum number of shots you need.

The recursive solution would be something like:

```
shots(200) = min(shots(200-24),shots(200-37),shots(200-54))
```

This would allow a trivial implementation, where the function `shot(n)` returns 0 if n is 0, some huge number if n is less than 0, and the expression above otherwise.

However, for large values of n you will hit the same values again and again, from different branches of the expression above. In that case, it's better just to start from 0 and calculate `shots(0)`, `shots(1)`, `shots(2)` etc. This would be the "dynamic programming" solution to this problem - using linear time and constant space instead of exponential time (traversing a 3-way tree) and linear space at best (for the call stack).

Comment: The top-down approach is still considered dynamic programming if you throw in memoization. Bottom-up DP and top-down DP are both DP.

Comment: @harold you're right, I probably should have added something about memoization (it's a bit more difficult to use if you want to keep the memory requirement reasonable, you need to know when you can "forget" values whereas with bottom-up it's pretty clear).

Comment: While the recursive solution with caching looks at only a small subset of the numbers 0..200, the iterative solution would have to look at all of them (at least it is not straightforward to avoid that). So, it seems that the recursive solution would run faster in this case.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg this really depends on the exact numbers, doesn't it? With 1, 3 and 5 units, recursion will not be very sparse. With a total distance of 120,000 recursion (with or without memoization) would require a lot more memory than DP. It's possible to find where each approach works best.

Comment: I fully agree with Omri and want to ask the following question. What would be a classical example of a problem for which the top-down recursive approach to DP (with caching) would result in a much simpler solution than the iterative approach? The "sparse" version of the problem in this thread is one example, but I am looking for a problem that's motivated by a practical application.